# Google signon email address into hidden field

Tags: javascript, forms, google-signin

I'm trying to use https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in to capture Google user name and Google email address in a  HTML hidden form field, but I'm having trouble.  Below is the code I have. I've very new to JavaScript. Thanks for your help!

```
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<form action="/student/webdesign/2016/02_benrud/tinker/googleVerify/loginHandler.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">

  <p>
    <input name="namelGoogle" type="hidden" id="nameGoogle" value="">
    <input name="mailGoogle" type="hidden" id="mailGoogle" value="">
  </p>
  <p> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </p>
</form>


<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
  document.getElementById("mailGoogle").value = profile.getName();
  document.getElementById("nameGoogle").value = profile.getEmail();
}

</script>
```

**Screenshot of the console**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/64IxLka.png]

I want email info to be captured in the hidden field named "mailGoogle".

I want name info to be captured in the hidden field named "nameGoogle".

1. What changes do I need to make to the `<script> </script>` tag (if any)
2. What changes do I need to make to the `<input name="emailGoogle" type="hidden" id="mailGoogle" value="I want email from google here">` tag

I am very new to JavaScript. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("mailGoogle").value = profile.getName();
document.getElementById("nameGoogle").value = profile.getEmail();
```

Make you Id's on your hidden fields unique and this should give you what you need.

The JQuery way would work as follows:

```
$('#nameGoogle').val(profile.getName());
$('#mailGoogle').val(profile.getEmail());
```

Comment: thanks for helping with this. I'm still very very new to JavaScript.  Can you please tell me where I add your above code? I've tried adding it to the value of the hidden form field and I've tried adding it in the <script> tag after the function. Neither worked. Any additional help / context is greatly appreciated. I did update the id names.

Comment: Try moving your form under     <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

Comment: Can you show me the two lines of code that you added. Did you add ids on your html tags to match the selectors above?

Comment: i've updated the code in the original question to reflect the my changes.